# Transferring data from excel to word in python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, file-handling

I'm attempting to write a script that allows me to read data from an input excel file (saved in .csv format because someone told me to do it that way), and write selected portions of this data to a word document.

It is a script to create personalised delivery notes for participants' meal choices (the choices are cumulatively added to an input spreadsheet).

So far I have created a dummy input spreadsheet, and saved a blank dummy output word file (dummy.csv and dummy.txt, respectively).

The code I have written so far reads the spreadsheet into the terminal, with some formatting to tidy it up.

```
import csv
f = open("dummy.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<20} {:<25}'.format(*row))
```

The output looks like this: (Dummy meal choices kept the same for ease)

```
Participant ID   Breakfasts       Lunches/dinners      Snacks
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111             Full english     Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
1111                              Risotto              Granola
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222             Avocado toast    Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
2222                              Bean chilli          Apple
```

My next challenge is to somehow write this data to a word file for participant 1111, another for participant 2222, and so on. I don't want the script to necessarily write the exact data from these rows to the word file, but rather whatever data could be on these rows should the food choices in the input file be different.

It would be good to keep the meals split into Breakfasts, Lunches/dinners, and Snacks on the output delivery note.

I can tidy up font etc later, I just want the meal selections to be there for now.
I'll also want to have it say "7 x Full english", rather than "Full english, Full english, Full english etc."

Thank you for reading, any help would be hugely appreciated!

Kieran

Comment: If you want to read in csv-files but then also make some calculations like counts as you stated, I'd recommend using `pandas`. With that also separate write-outs of sub groups into different files is no problem. But honestly, up to now I did not really understand what exactly you want to do....

Comment: Thanks for your response - I really am extremely new to this so pardon me for not being clear.
I am attempting to have a python script that will, when executed, open a master spreadsheet (into which the meal choices of all participants for that week have been entered), select all of participant 1111's choices and output a delivery note listing all of the meals to be delivered to participant 1111 that week. 

The output will have Participant ID (1111), Breakfasts: 7 x Full english, Lunches/Dinners: 14 x Risotto, and so on. Then, the same task repeated for all participants.

Comment: No reason to pardon - I think you really should have a closer look at pandas. It's already a very powerful tool for data analysis and is actively developedon. And if I look at your profile, I think you'll be happy to use it in the future again and again...

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Just to show where you exemplary could go using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('whereverfilemayroam/filename')

    Participant ID     Breakfasts Lunches/dinners   Snacks
0             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
1             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
2             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
3             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
4             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
5             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
6             1111   Full english         Risotto  Granola
7             1111           None         Risotto  Granola
8             1111           None         Risotto  Granola
9             1111           None         Risotto  Granola
10            1111           None         Risotto  Granola
11            1111           None         Risotto  Granola
12            1111           None         Risotto  Granola
13            1111           None         Risotto  Granola
14            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
15            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
16            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
17            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
18            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
19            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
20            2222  Avocado toast     Bean chilli    Apple
21            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
22            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
23            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
24            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
25            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
26            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
27            2222           None     Bean chilli    Apple
```

That's your file in a pandas dataframe, the standard container in pandas, if you like. And now you can make a *plenty* of statistical things with it... Just dig a little through the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)
Examples:

```
df.groupby(['Participant ID', 'Breakfasts']).Breakfasts.count()

Participant ID  Breakfasts   
1111            Full english     7
2222            Avocado toast    7
Name: Breakfasts, dtype: int64

df.groupby(['Participant ID', 'Lunches/dinners'])['Lunches/dinners'].count()

Participant ID  Lunches/dinners
1111            Risotto            14
2222            Bean chilli        14
Name: Lunches/dinners, dtype: int64
```

Of course you can separate by Participant ID:

```
oneoneoneone = df[df['Participant ID'] == 1111]

oneoneoneone

    Participant ID    Breakfasts Lunches/dinners   Snacks
0             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
1             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
2             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
3             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
4             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
5             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
6             1111  Full english         Risotto  Granola
7             1111          None         Risotto  Granola
8             1111          None         Risotto  Granola
9             1111          None         Risotto  Granola
10            1111          None         Risotto  Granola
11            1111          None         Risotto  Granola
12            1111          None         Risotto  Granola
13            1111          None         Risotto  Granola


oneoneoneone.to_csv('target_file')
```

and so would perhaps

```
twotwotwotwo.to_csv('another_target_file')
```

One can also iterate over groups, and then apply always the same operations on each group.
e.g.:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Participant ID'):
    print(name)
    print(group.groupby('Breakfasts').Breakfasts.count().to_string())
    print(group.groupby('Lunches/dinners')['Lunches/dinners'].count().to_string())
    print(group.groupby('Snacks').Snacks.count().to_string(), '\n')
```

returns:

```
1111
Breakfasts
Full english    7
Lunches/dinners
Risotto    14
Snacks
Granola    14 

2222
Breakfasts
Avocado toast    7
Lunches/dinners
Bean chilli    14
Snacks
Apple    14
```